# Базы данных, где их взять?

Tags: база-данных, поиск-данных

Посоветуйте какой-нибудь сайт из которого можно будет взять базы данных для обработки, потому что хочу потренироваться, а найти не могу ничего нормального

Comment: Обработки чего? База данных какая - оракл, мускул, постгрес, монга?

Comment: обычно какие-нить стандартные учебные материалы по СУБД сопровождаются учебной БД

Comment: Сайт, которые содержит базы данных на любые темы. А какая она это не важно: оракул, постгрес, монга

Answer (score 1):

Для Sql Server существует несколько учебных баз данных.

[Northwind and pubs](https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/databases/northwind-pubs).

[AdventureWorks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/samples/adventureworks-install-configure?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=ssms).

Ищите по этим названиям: pubs, Northwind, AdventureWorks - и вы найдёте множество учебных материалов с этими БД.

Вот ещё: [NorthDynamic](https://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic-sql/NorthDynamic.sql.txt), используется в этой [статье](https://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).