# Где найти готовые базы данных хороших проектов?

Tags: sql, база-данных

Где можно найти показательные базы данных каких-либо проектов. Создать базу данных, со знаниями студента, могу, но как качественно создать базу данных для того же онлайн-магазина, не достаточно знаний. Нужны такие базы данных, в которых есть таблицы для токенов, аккаунтов, товаров и т.д. Гугля этот вопрос не находил толкового решения.

Comment: Вероятно, следует искать примеры баз данных для конкретных СУБД. Например, для Sql Server: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1421816/184217

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для SQL Server на сайте Microsoft есть 2 тренировочные БД:

- [AdventureWorks](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/samples/adventureworks-install-configure?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=ssms)
- [Wide World Importers](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/samples/wide-world-importers-what-is?view=sql-server-ver16)